# knockout beforeRemove : is it like a database "instead" trigger?

Tags: knockout.js

Is my understanding correct, that if a `beforeRemove` handler is set on the container-div in a foreach binding, this causes knockout *not* to remove the item? In other words, **beforeRemove** is like an "instead" trigger in a database?

Comment: Yes, if you're using the `beforeRemove` or `beforeMove` handlers you are responsible to remove the element from DOM and KO won't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. If you'll make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: if you are using the `beforeRemove` or `beforeMove` handlers you are responsible to remove the DOM nodes.

This is also stated in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_7_postprocessing_or_animating_the_generated_dom_elements):

> `beforeRemove` — is invoked when an array item has been removed, but
>   before the corresponding DOM nodes have been removed. If you specify a
>   beforeRemove callback, then *it becomes your responsibility to remove
>   the DOM nodes.*

You can easily try this out with adding an empty `beforeRemove` handler and the items won't be removed automatically:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: items, beforeRemove: function() { }}">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span> 
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/xQbuP/).

Comment: From the description of the parameters sent to the beforeRemove handler, one would assume that knockout has already removed the item from the observable array. It refers to the item as the "removed" item, not as the to-be-removed item.  The index is the item's `former` index?

Comment: KO will call `beforeRemove` AFTER the item has been removed from the observable array but BEFORE the DOM nodes removed. So the second parameter (`item`) is the already removed item. And the third parameter (`index`) is the index from where it was removed.